# This puzzle is a loss

Tags: knowledge, sequence

What should replace the question mark on this list?

> JBNRS, HF, GM, JPD, VL, AELMP, MS, WB, CB, GS, EC, SV, PD, PEJP, ?, …

Hint, added later:

> There's a hint alluded to via wordplay in the post title.

Hint, added even later:

> Although I list JBNRS first, there was, some five or six years earlier, PHCS. But PHCS doesn't really count.

Comment: Is the question mark part of the question?

Comment: @Jingbothedude, the question mark signifies missing term you need to supply. Would it be clearer if I omitted the "?,"?

Comment: @msh210 It's fine - leave it in. The meaning of a question mark is pretty universal! :)  (If you want clarity, ask what comes **fifteenth** in this list, or what replaces the question mark in this list, perhaps, but I don't think it's really necessary...)

Comment: Msh I think these might be initials or some letters are missing in some other way might be added but I was asking about a hint on the knowledge tag.

Comment: @Smartest1here I'll probably provide another hint at least day after the first, if there's no apparent headway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question mark should be replaced with

> CHP

This is the list of

> the [presidents of the European Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_European_Parliament#List_of_office_holders), given by their initials:
>
>  1958-1960 JBNRS = Jean-Baptiste Nicolas Robert Schuman
>  1960-1962 HF = Hans Furler
>  1962-1964 GM = Gaetano Martino
>  1964-1965 JPD = Jean Pierre Duvieusart
>  1965-1966 VL = Victor Leemans
>  1966-1969 AELMP = Alain Émile Louis Marie Poher
>  1969-1971 MS = Mario Scelba
>  1971-1973 WB = Walter Behrendt
>  1973-1975 CB = Cornelis Berkhouwer
>  1975-1977 GS = Georges Spénale
>  1977-1979 EC = Emilio Colombo
>  1979-1982 SV = Simone Veil
>  1982-1984 PD = Piet Dankert
>  1984-1987 PEJP = Pierre Eugène Jean Pflimlin
>  1987-1989 CHP = Charles Henry Plumb

As for the hints:

> Hint 1: <s>I don't really get the wordplay. Maybe "a loss" because every one in the list is dead???</s> "is a loss" is the anagram of [Sassoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Sassoli), the current president (thanks user39583)

> Hint 2: PHCS (Paul-Henri Charles Spaak) was the president of the Common Assembly of the European Coal and Steel Community which predates the European Community. The EEC started in 1958 with Robert Schuman (JBNRS) as first president.

Comment: It must be the answer surely, but OPs hints and title make no sense. Also how did you manage to figure this out??

Comment: rot13("vf n ybff" vf na nantenz bs Fnffbyv, gur pheerag cerfvqrag)

Comment: @flinty (I added my thoughts about the hints in my answer) I found JBNRS early, by trials and errors, using Wikipedia search auto-completion. I didn't manage to find a second name then I threw in the towel. Then came hint #2 and, with the same method, I came to [rot13(Fcnnx'f JC cntr)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul-Henri_Spaak) which mentions rot13(Eboreg Fpuhzna).

Comment: @user39583 Great! That must be it; amending my answer then

Comment: Well found, @xhienne!

Comment: @msh210 Finally a puzzle that is not americanocentric! ;-)